# Using a value in PHP for a HTML div

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to get this done for the past half an hour and it just doesn't seem it work. 
I thought that passing a value in PHP to html would just be like

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo '100%;'; ?>">
```

but the width part doesn't seem to accept the php value since the progress bar doesn't fill. Have I formatted it wrong or something...?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this on your server/xampp?

Comment: since you are using a hard coded value `100%` the use of php is pointless. Is this a contrived example?

Comment: Anyway, a div will default to 100% unless other styles are attached to it, so you will at least need to show your css, and the generated html (view source) to make sure there isnt some syntax error missed in the example above

Comment: @Steve it is just an example. I want to later on use a php variable instead.

Comment: @C0dekid Yes I am

Comment: Does `style="width: 100%;"` work?  I suspect not, in which case the issue is css not php

Comment: @Steve Yes it does.

Comment: so what does the generated html look like (view source, not inspect element)

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by the generated html? Do you mean the output?

Comment: right click in your browser, select 'view source' and see what the html looks like

Comment: @Steve I already posted the HTML.

Comment: So if you do exactly as i just stated (via view source) you can see `<?php ...`? If so then you dont have php installed correctly / your server is not running the file through the php interpreter.

Comment: @Steve Well I tried running a basic hello world program in a new php file and that worked fine. Why isn't the php interpreted in this scenario then?

Comment: whats the file extension? How are you accessing the page in the browser?  via http://localhost/somepage.php or a file url?

Comment: I tried it both on my local server and on my web server. Both index.html

Comment: @Steve Nvm, I changed the extension to .php and it worked. Stupid mistake I guess... Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Vyres No problem, you got it sorted, and learned something, so no wasted time

Answer (score 0):

Simply needed to change the file extension to `.php` instead of `.html`

Comment: I wrote it in my answer. So I don't understand why you didn't mark it as correct and added your own. This doesn't work like this.

Answer (score -1):

This would work only in files interpreted by PHP parser. Usually `*.php`. And on a server.

But... don't do it :)

Don't mess these two languages together. They're for different things.

It's very old fashioned.

Unless you use Wordpress or something like this where you have to do it this way.

Comment: This isn't the case. Later on I am going to be using variables in php which will be used in the HTML form. So I have to use the php.

Comment: Looks like the guess was correct. Remove the unwarrented opinion and this could be marked as correct

Comment: @Steve Why unwarranted? Looked like first steps in web development to me so I think it's good to advice to split server and client sides like this works nowadays.

Comment: I didnt downvote you, but i think the opinion is unwarranted because server side rendering is still by far the most prevalent method of making websites (not webapps). I totally agree you should separate presentation from business logic (MVC for example) but you still need basic presentation logic in the view, and php is very good template language.

Comment: @Steve yes but in this case something like Twig is a solution. Mixing PHP and HTML in the direct output like here is a very bad idea in my opinion. Cheers!